# Oracle 11g query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a query that will alter the required data in a table if another column meets certain criteria. It will need to compare the "Last_logon" column to the SYSDATE, if the Last_logon date was prior to the (SYSDATE - 45 days) I want it to change a column in the table called "STATUS" from 'Active' to 'Inactive'.

Below is what I have written so far but one issue is that the "Last_logon" column is data type varchar2 and is in the format Month, DD YYYY HH:MM.  Any suggestions would be great I have tried to "convert" the varchar2 to a date data type but that only resulted in numerous error messages.

```
ALTER TABLE technician_tbl
ALTER COLUMN 'STATUS'
WHERE 'Last_logon' > (SYSDATE -45);
```

Comment: Show us what you tried to convert it to and how the errormessages looked like

Comment: That query is meaningless in Oracle.

Comment: A hint: The ALTER TABLE statement modifies the schema of a table, i.e. it adds columns, deletes columns, renames columns etc. That's not what you want. You want to change the data in a table. That's what the UPDATE (or possibly MERGE) statement is for.

Comment: Thanks I will read up on that a little and try again.  Ill post whatever results I get. I am brand new to this.

Comment: Change "last_logon" to a  DATE datatype .. NEVER store a date as a string .. it'll only hurt you later ... guaranteed.

Comment: Wait, isn't some kind of triggering event required to manipulate data based on an action?

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE technician_tbl
>   ALTER COLUMN 'STATUS'
>   WHERE 'Last_logon' > (SYSDATE -45);

I don't believe that it is a valid query syntax in Oracle.

> one issue is that the "Last_logon" column is data type varchar2 and is in the format Month, DD YYYY HH:MM.

You are struggling between a **STRING** and an actual **DATE**. But, it is not the main issue regarding your question.

> if the Last_logon date was prior to the (SYSDATE - 45 days) I want it to change a column in the table called "STATUS" from 'Active' to 'Inactive'.

To manipulate data based on an action, requires a **trigger** or some alternative to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
UPDATE technician_tbl
  SET status = 'Inactive'
  WHERE TO_DATE(last_logon, 'MONTH, DD YYYY HH:MM) < SYSDATE - 45;

COMMIT;
```

I assume that the column *Last_logon* is in fact called LAST_LOGON. If it really uses mixed case spelling, you would need to put its name in double quotes: `"Last_Logon"`.

Answer (score 0):

If have just tried it against a Oracle 9 database. What you are looking for is something similar to this:

```
Update Technician_tbl 
Set Status = 'Inactive'
Where TO_DATE(Last_Logon, "MM.DD.YYYY HH:MM") > (SYSDATE -45)
```

Assuming your `Last_Logon` really has the format `MM.DD.YYYY HH:MM`. If last logon has another format, you need to change the `To_Date()` function accordingly.

If Last_Logon is in the format `MONTH, DD YYYY HH:MM` the function would be `TO_DATE(Last_Logon, 'MONTH, DD YYYY HH:MM')`

Since you are new to the world of SQL: If you are using SQL plus you might need to add a `COMMIT` to the end of your query in order to write your changes to your database.

Further information:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm